# invoking android 4.0.3 from deep sleep

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Any idea how to invoke a device running on a ics 4.0.3 i am not able to do so with power manager and alarm manager.
I hv tried it with services and all given by different forum but no hope.
any idea how to do it programming.

Comment: `AlarmManager` works perfectly well on 4.0.3.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am using  google nexus s ics its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

When you're writing about the PowerManager - do you mean [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)? Usually this would be the solution to waking up a sleeping device. Make sure to use it in some kind of singleton and be aware of the four different types documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

You need to make sure that you have this permission in your manifest:

```
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: i hv tried the alarm manager also but when device manually wakeup via power button alarm works fine but when it goes to deep sleep its nt working